# How to detect DOM update completion after AJAX page load in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I'm trying to identify roughly when the DOM is finished updating after a page is loaded via AJAX on any arbitrary website.

My current method first listens for the `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` event in a background script, then executes a content script in which a `MutationObserver` detects changes to the website's body. From there, unfortunately, it seems like it's a bit more finicky. If I just wait for the first mutation where nodes are added to the DOM, I wind up in many cases (YouTube, to give one example) where the page is still blank. Other more hacky approaches I've considered include things like just using setTimeout or waiting for the page to reach a certain length, but those seem clearly wide open to exception cases.

Is there a more fool-proof way to detect that the DOM has roughly finished updating? It doesn't necessarily have to be perfectly precise, and erring on the side of triggering late in my use case is better than triggering early. Also it isn't important at all that resources like video and images be fully loaded, just that the text contents of the page are basically in place.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The usual approach is to *debounce* the processing function from within the observer callback.

Comment: This is brilliant wOxxOm, thank you so much! Somehow I've managed to miss debouncing in my research, but it's a fantastic solution. Cheers!